# Using combinatios and unions in Python

Tags: python-3.x

**This is a homework code, I will need help understanding why the code doesn't run currently and what I can do to fix it**

The homework problem is opening a file of some numbers. The first number will represent a room number, room[0], and the second number represents a room number, room[1], that is adjacent to the first room; this continues on until the code has iterated though the whole text document. It will then produce a adjacency matrix. This is done with a class. I have this part complete, and it works like it should.

The next part is finding the minimum number of "TA's" are needed to cover the rooms, and what rooms to place the TA's in so that through the connected rooms a TA can be in every room. Basically greedy algorithm.

Here is a visual example of the out come of the test file I will share:

```
    TAs needed: 2
    TAs assigned to rooms: 2, 5
    Adjacency Matrix
    1: 2
    2: 1 3
    3: 2 4
    4: 3 5
    5: 4 6
    6: 5
```

What this means, there are 6 study rooms and they connect to the rooms that are listed next to them. The minimum number of TAs required to service all 6 rooms is 2, and to make sure a TA can be in every room one needs to be placed in room 2 and the other in room 5.

Naturally, the part I need help with is finding the minimum number of TAs and which rooms to put them in. I know what I need to do, for the most part, but I don't know how to get there. Here is my code:

```
import itertools

class Matrix(object):
    '''
    Class to create a matrix of adjacent rooms. 
    '''

    def __init__(self):  # no modification is needed for this method, but you may modify it if you wish to
        '''
        Create and initialize your class attributes.
        '''
        self._matrix = []
        self._rooms = 0

    def read_file(self,fp):  #fp is a file pointer
        '''
        Function reads the given file and returns a matrix
        '''

        self._rooms = int(fp.readline())
        for i in range(self._rooms + 1):
            self._matrix.append(set())
        for line in fp:
            line = line.split()
            x = int(line[0])
            y = int(line[1])
            self._matrix[x].add(y)
            self._matrix[y].add(x)

        return self._matrix


    def __str__(self):
        '''
        '''
        s = ''
        for i,L in enumerate(self._matrix):
            if i > 0:
               s += "{}: {}\n".format( i,' '.join(str(l) for l in L) ) 
        return  "Adjancency Matrix: \n{}".format(s) 


    def __repr__(self):  # no modification need of this method
        '''
        Call __str__() to return a string for displaying in the shell
        '''
        return self.__str__()  

    def adjacent(self,index):
        '''
        Return the set of connecting rooms to room specified by index
        '''
        return self._matrix[index]

    def rooms(self):
        '''Return the number of rooms
        '''
        return self._rooms


def open_file():

    ''' Function to open a file, if the file does not exsist 
    it will return an error message and ask the user to input the file name.
    '''
    while True:
        prompt = input("\nEnter the name of the file: ")
        try:
            fp = open(prompt,'r')
            return fp
            #where fp is the file pointer that will be used throughout the code
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("\nFile not found, please try again. ")


def main():
    '''
    Main function determines the number of TAs needed to cover each
    room
    '''
    TAs=0
    enough = True
    list_of_rooms = set()
    fp = open_file()
    matrix = Matrix()
    file = matrix.read_file(fp)
    x = set()
    while True:
        TAs +=1
        if enough != False:
            for room in file:
                list_of_rooms=(room)

                for tup_set in itertools.combinations(list_of_rooms, TAs):
                    for i in tup_set:
                        x.update(matrix.adjacent(i).union(matrix.adjacent(TAs)))
                        if x == set():
                            enough = True
                        else:
                            print("TAs Needed: {}".format(TAs))
                            print( "TAs assigned to rooms: {}".format(x))
                            enough = False
        elif enough == False:
            break                 

    print(matrix.__str__())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The file to open is:

```
6
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
```

The top most single number of the file indicates the total number of rooms.

I know that using itertools.combinations will give me the total number of combinations of rooms the number of TAs can be in. I know that I can use union to find which rooms to put the TAs in, but I can't seem to 1: determine the number of TAs correctly and 2: correctly print the rooms to put them in.

I need some help in understanding how to complete this problem. I apologize for the length of the question, I could not think of a way to shorten it.